# Nginx Static Configuration - Misdirected

Tags: nginx

Nginx pointing to the static directory

I can’t figure out where I am going wrong here. I am trying to point Nginx to my static directory for the CSS and JS.

The true location of my static folder is as follows:

- /var/www/site/app/static
- /var/www/site/app/static/js
- /var/www/site/app/static/css

In my app_nginx.conf I have this:

```
location /static {
root /var/www/site/app/static;
index index.html;
}
```

When I go to my site it is looking for the content in this folder:

```
http://localhost/static/css/main.css
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected this, you shouldnt include the static folder in the root directive, it should have been like this:

```
root /var/www/site/app;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use something similar to the following.

```
root /var/www/site/app/static;

location / {
  index index.html;
}
```

Then you should be able to use the following url to hit your content

```
http://localhost/css/main.css
```